# Raspberry PI Zero W

Tags: usb, serial, pi-zero-w

I do not have any Raspberry Pi experience.

I can connect to my Raspberry Pi Zero W with ssh and Remote Desktop. The Raspberry is connected to a motor controller called 'Sabertooth 2x32'.

The Sabertooth has the ability to be controlled via serial input through its USB port. The Sabertooth has its own power source.

The bot is a lawnmower. I currently control the bot via RC through the Sabertooth. It works.

But now I would like to control the bot from the Internet.

But how do I send serial commands to the Sabertooth from the raspberry? It seems USB from Raspberry to Sabertooth would be simplest. Don't have to mess with the GPIOs then.

But...I just do not know where to start. Are there any apps I can install that would do this? Like a web server for the raspberry that would allow me to live stream my camera and use like a virtual joystick to control the bot? Maybe an Xbox controller from my PC.

I apologize for my lack of knowledge; and I have been googling. If you just want to drop a link to get me started that's cool

Comment: You can create a Website or an API to control the Sabertooth, Are you using any scripts now to control it? If yes, what?

Comment: No I do not have a script controlling it. I can control via RC right now though

Comment: In the desktop in the Pi Configuration settings, I had to enable the Serial to use the USB Serial devices. Type lsusb in a terminal to see the usb devices. Install gtkterm, configure it for the right serial port and try to type commands to the USB Serial. If that works you can use other linux serial programs and scripts. The next step is to connect to the USB Serial via wifi. Search for: wifi to serial linux

Answer (score 1):

I too am about to build a Robot using a Sabertooth 2 x 32 and want to control it via R/C and Serial. I also noticed that it can be controlled via USB Serial without the need for a Logic Level Shifter.

I have previously built a web interface using Webiopi to control a Raspberry Pi Robot but had a n Arduino Nano connected to the Motor Controller (This will soon be removed and the Robot will be controlled directly with the Pi.

Do you want the Lawnmower to have a Camera onboard so you can see where it is? With WebioPi you create a web Page in HTML and and use the Pi and WebioPi as a web server. Here is [my Instructable](https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Web-Controlled-Autonomous-Robot/) with a link to the code (it is not very detailed but may give you some ideas).
https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Web-Controlled-Autonomous-Robot/